# Django Template is not displaying the table data

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-viewsets

I am hoping someone can show me where I am going wrong. In one template I have a table that displays a few rows of data. I want a link in one of the fields to open a separate template for that field.

The print commands display the correct information:
print(vendor) displays: Sandpiper
print(searchresult) displays: <QuerySet [<Vendor: Sandpiper>]>

Sandpiper matches the name of the vendor in the vendor table, but when executed the detail page loads but does not display any of the data from the Vendors table.

```
views.py
def utilvendorview(request, vendor):

    searchresult = Vendor.objects.filter(search=vendor)
    print(vendor)
    print(searchresult)
        
    return render(request,'utilityrentals/vendors_detail.html',{"searchresult":searchresult})
```

```
urls.py
path('utilvendorview/<vendor>/', views.utilvendorview, name='utilityvendor'),
```

```
index.html (main template)
<td><a href="utilvendorview/{{ results.Vendor  }}">{{ results.Vendor }}</a></td>
```

```
vendors_detail.html - Trying to have this populate
{% extends "maintenance_base.html" %}

{% load static from static %}

{% block body %}
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                          <div class="card-body">
                           <h5 class="card-title">{{ Vendor.company }}</h5>
                           <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Email Address: {{ searchresult.email1 }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Email Address: {{ searchresult.email2 }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Phone: {{ searchresult.phone1 }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Mobile: {{ searchresult.phone2 }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Category: {{ searchresult.category }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Address1: {{ searchresult.address1 }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Address2: {{ searchresult.address2 }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">City: {{ searchresult.city }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Province: {{ searchresult.province }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Postal Code: {{ searchresult.postal }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Notes: {{ searchresult.notes }} </h6>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Active: {{ searchresult.active }} </h6>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems that you are trying to get attributes of an instance from a queryset.

```
searchresult = Vendor.objects.filter(search=vendor)
```

As you have printed in terminal, this gives you a queryset. And you cannot get attributes from queryset as queryset is a list of instances not an instance.

To fix this,

```
searchresult = Vendor.objects.get(search=vendor)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfect and thank you for explaining where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You try my example

```html
{% block body %}
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ Vendor.company }}</h5>
                        {% for sc in searchresult %}
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Email Address: {{ sc.email1 }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Email Address: {{ sc.email2 }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Phone: {{ sc.phone1 }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Mobile: {{ sc.phone2 }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Category: {{ sc.category }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Address1: {{ sc.address1 }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Address2: {{ sc.address2 }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">City: {{ sc.city }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Province: {{ sc.province }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Postal Code: {{ sc.postal }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Notes: {{ sc.notes }} </h6>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Active: {{ sc.active }} </h6>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer will be perfect if there will be multiple number of vendors in your searchresult. As the you will be returning an 'n' number of instances inside a queryset.
Then in your template you will be looping through every instances which is basically done here.